# Java.lang.exception while creating an object

Tags: java

I am trying to make an assignment where I have to check if rectangels overlap or not and a few other methods. I have almost completed it but I cant create new objects from the class. It is giving me
**Error:(121, 32) java: unreported exception java.lang.Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown** Here is my code

```
  /**
 * Created by Sarang on 18-10-2014.
 */
import java.awt.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.io.*;


public class Rectangle {
    private int upper_x, upper_y, lower_x, lower_y;

    public Rectangle(int upper1, int upper2,int lower1,int lower2) throws Exception {
        this.upper_x=upper1;
        this.upper_y=upper2;
        this.lower_x=lower1;
        this.lower_y=lower2;
        try {
            if (upper_x > lower_x || upper_y > lower_y)
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();   //Checking if the rectangle is valid
            }
            if(lower_x  >500)
            {lower_x=500;}
            if(lower_y>500)
            {lower_y=500;}  //Setting the lower bounds to 500
            if(upper_x<50)
            {upper_x=50;}
            if(upper_y<50)
            {upper_y=50;}
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException IAE) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Rectangle");
        }
    }
    Rectangle( Rectangle other)
    {
        upper_x=other.upper_x;
        upper_y=other.upper_y;
        lower_x=other.lower_x;
        lower_y=other.lower_y;
    }
    public boolean overlap(Rectangle other)
    {
        if(upper_x<other.upper_x && upper_y<other.upper_y && lower_x>other.lower_x && lower_y>other.lower_y)
              { return false;}
        if (!( lower_y < other.upper_y || upper_y > other.lower_y || lower_x < other.upper_x || upper_x > other.lower_x ))
              { return true;}
        return false;
    }
    public boolean containedIn(Rectangle other)
    {
        if(upper_x<other.upper_x && upper_y<other.upper_y && lower_x>other.lower_x && lower_y>other.lower_y)
            { return true;}
        if(other.upper_x<upper_x && other.upper_y<upper_y && other.lower_x>lower_x && other.lower_y>lower_y)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public boolean drag(int x, int y)
    {
        int temp_1x=upper_x;
        int temp_1y=upper_y;
        int temp_2x=lower_x;
        int temp_2y=lower_y;
        int length=lower_x-upper_x;
        int height=lower_y-upper_y;
        upper_x=x-length/2;
        upper_y=y-height/2;
        lower_x=x+length/2;
        lower_x=y+height/2;
        if(upper_x<50||upper_y<50||lower_x>500||lower_y>500)
        {
            upper_x=temp_1x;
            upper_y=temp_1y;
            lower_x=temp_2x;
            lower_y=temp_2y;
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }

    public boolean resize(int x, int y)
    {
        int temp_x,temp_y;
        temp_x=lower_x;
        temp_y=lower_y;

        lower_x=x;
        lower_y=y;
        if (upper_x > lower_x || upper_y > lower_y)
        {
            lower_x=temp_x;
            lower_y=temp_y;
            return false;
        }
        if(lower_x  >500||lower_y>500)
        {
            lower_x=temp_x;
            lower_y=temp_y;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public int getUpperX(){return upper_x;}
    public int getUpperY(){return upper_y;}
    public int getLowerX(){return lower_x;}
    public int getLowerY(){return lower_y;}



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Rectangle rectangle1 = new Rectangle(60,70,400,400);
        Rectangle rectangle2 = new Rectangle(100,100,450,450);
        System.out.println("rectangle1.overlap(rectangle2):"  + rectangle1.overlap(rectangle2));
        System.out.println("rectangle1.containedIn(rectangle2):" +rectangle1.containedIn(rectangle2));

    }


    /*
     *
     * The code below this comment is for visual display of a 2D array of Rectangles.
     * You are not supposed to make any changes or add any code below this comment.
     *
     */
    class showRecs extends JFrame {
        public showRecs(Rectangle[] rectArr) {
//         super("Display Arrays");
//         Rectangle[] r1 = rt.rArr;
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            displayRecs recs = new displayRecs();
            getContentPane().add(recs);
            for (int i = 0; i < rectArr.length; i++) {
                int w = rectArr[i].getLowerX() - rectArr[i].getUpperX();
                int h = rectArr[i].getLowerY() - rectArr[i].getUpperY();
                recs.addArrays(rectArr[i].getUpperX(), rectArr[i].getUpperY(), w, h);
            }

            pack();
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setVisible(true);

        }

    }

    class displayRecs extends JPanel {
        private static final int frame_width = 500;
        private static final int frame_height = frame_width;
        private List<java.awt.Rectangle> rects = new ArrayList<java.awt.Rectangle>();

        public void addArrays(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            java.awt.Rectangle rect = new java.awt.Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
            rects.add(rect);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(frame_width, frame_height);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            for (java.awt.Rectangle rect : rects) {
                Random rand = new Random();
                int R = rand.nextInt(255);
                int G = rand.nextInt(255);
                int B = rand.nextInt(255);

                Color color = new Color(R, G, B);
                g.setColor(color);
                g.drawString("(" + rect.x + "," + rect.y + ")", rect.x - 45, rect.y);
                int m = rect.x + rect.width;
                int l = rect.y + rect.height;
                int idx = rects.indexOf(rect);
                g.drawString("(" + m + "," + l + ")", m + 1, l + 1);
                int locx = rect.x + rect.width / 2;
                int locy = rect.y + rect.height / 2;
                g.drawString((String.valueOf(idx)), locx, locy);
                g2.draw(rect);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

What have I done wrong in code. I have yet to apply some other methods but it is not running at this stage

Comment: What exactly in phrase "must be caught or declared to be thrown" you do not understand?

Comment: @talex Actually I did not know why it was coming. Sorry for the silly question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
public Rectangle(int upper1, int upper2,int lower1,int lower2) throws Exception {
                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That is saying that your `Rectangle` constructor can throw *any* kind of exception. That means any code that calls the constructor has to deal with any kind of exception (either by catching it or also declaring it as thrown).

It looks like your constructor is actually only throwing `IllegalArgumentException`, which is unchecked (doesn't need to be declared in a `throws` clause). So if you take off the `throws`, it should work.

```
public Rectangle(int upper1, int upper2,int lower1,int lower2) {
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I removed the "throws exception" and its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

As your constructor throws an exception you can only call `new` on the Rectangle class within a try/catch block that catches `Exception`

Answer (score 1):

our basic problems is that you have declared that the Constructor for rectangle can throw an exception (which it doesn't so this declaration is strange).

In you main program you cannot instantiate the object because this would invoke the constructor - now the compiler knows the constructor might throw an exception (because you declared it that way) so it won't let you instantiate the instance because you don't have a try - catch surrounding the instantiation.

So in summary I don't think you want the throws ... part of the declaration on the constructor - if you do for some (future) reason need this constructor to throw then you must put a suitable try-catch around the declaration to catch the potential throw.

Comment: Thanks. The code worked after removing  throws exception

Answer (score 0):

your constructor looks like this :

```
public Rectangle(int upper1, int upper2,int lower1,int lower2) throws Exception
```

the `throws Exception` means it is likely to throw an exception which means, the caller (here your main method), needs to `try-catch` it.